# How to reload view controller on iOS

Tags: ios, methods, reload, viewdidload

Is there a way to reload the view controller not through calling the method `-viewDidLoad`?
I was searching my problem in Google, and the Solutions found was to call to `-viewDidLoad` and i want to reload the view controller, Like open the app at first.

how can I do that?

Comment: you should never need calling `viewDidLoad`. Please, explain what you are trying to achieve...

Answer (score 0):

You should never call `-viewDidLoad` method directly. It's called automatically whenever your view controller's view loads for the first time.

As far as I can understand from provided description, what you're trying to achieve can be done using custom setup method in `-viewDidLoad` and then calling it again later to "reload" your view controller.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self setupViewController];
}

- (void)setupViewController {
  // any custom setup you need to do
}
```

Comment: No No No No No... I want to Reload the ViewController.. close it and open it again..